# How do I include an HTML tag with its attributes as a string inside an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsx

[image: html tag]

I want to include this html tag with those exact colors inside an element inside a JSX environment.
I tried doing it like this:
`const htmlTag = '<ifx-icon icon="calendar-16"></ifx-icon>';`
and then I render it inside an element `<div>{htmlTag}</div>`
and this works, but how do I now select the various parts of the string? How do I select `<ifx-icon>`, `icon` etc in order to color it differently?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are after a **Code Syntax Highlighter**.

Because you mentioned `jsx`, I'm *assuming* you are using React.

You could try a package called `react-syntax-highlighter`.

https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter#readme

**EDIT**

I know you mentioned you are not using React, but I coded a VERY simple example of what you could do if you don't want to use any libs.

```
function encodeHtml(html) {
  return html.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/g, i => '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';');
}

function colorHtml(html) {
  return encodeHtml(html)
    .replace(/ifx-icon/g, '<span style="color:green">ifx-icon</span>')
    .replace(/\sicon/g, '<span style="color:blue"> icon</span>');
}

const App = () => {
  const data = colorHtml('<ifx-icon icon="c-check-16"></ifx-icon>');

  return (
    <pre>
      <code dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}/>
    </pre>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-khorana-sq57k5?file=/src/App.js

Again, this is just a proof of concept, tweak the regex/string replacement to meet your requirements.

Comment: I am using Stencil.js, which also uses JSX. Is there any other way to do it without installing any dependencies?

Comment: See my edited answer above

Comment: Thanks. I already figured out how to do it. I just broke every part of it, and then assembled it inside the html. But what is left now is to figure out what is this font family? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Already figured out. It was monospace :)